# iOS: get downloaded, uploaded and downloaded speed by NetworkExtension framework

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, networkextension

Can I get it from NetworkExtension framework? I am using it in VPN app and need to get info from current connection.
I need data how much MB was downloaded and uploaded and download speed.

Comment: not only is your question not very clear but it also looks like you haven't done any research yourself. please explain your issue properly and explain what you have tried already and we will try to help. otherwise your question will likely get downvotes or be closed as its too broad and not clear as it is right now

Comment: @Scriptable i need to show how many bytes was uploaded and downloaded, but can not find methods how can i get them